# How to give shadow to dropdown with a pointed triangle?

Tags: css

I want to give some shadow to dropdown with pointed aero. 
Shadow is working well with dropdown but somehow not able to apply it on pointer.

```
.dropdown{
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 310px;height: 70%;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: @light-color;
    -webkit-border-radius: @border-radius;
    -moz-border-radius: @border-radius;
    border-radius: @border-radius;
    top: 44px;left: 44px;z-index: 9999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #aaa;
}

.dropdown:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 14px 14px;
    border-color: #f4f5f4 transparent;
    display: block;width: 0;
    z-index: 999;top: -14px;left: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
}
```

Comment: Here's a demo fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/enworl/jtj0kawn/)

Comment: There is no triangle in your JSfiddle.

Comment: Temporary I've made it red. Please check now. [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/enworl/jtj0kawn/2/)

Comment: @Jay that fiddle has a square shadow around the triangle, not helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two way to achieve what you want :

First use unicode caractere:

HTML :

```
<div class="unicode">&#9650;</div>
```

CSS :

```
.unicode {
   color: #999;
   text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   font-size:3em;
}
```

Second use pseudo element `after` to add a rotate div and crop them inside the parent:

HTML :

```
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

CSS :

```
.triangle {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   box-shadow: 0 16px 10px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.triangle::after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: #999;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   top: 75px;
   left: 25px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Think to add all prefixe for more browser compatibility

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/j4hcev21/3**